# Event Listener from for each works with just one child

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase, event-handling

okay so i'm bout to lose my hair have been trying to fix this all day long and always end with the same result ,

what am trying to do is getting data from firebase and that work just fine , the issue is i wanna click on the big box and then get the buttons value from the clicked box it works with the first box and never work with any other box .

```
function gotData(data) {

  // got data array
  all = data.val();
  var keys = Object.keys(all);
  if (keys === 'null') { return null;}
  for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    var k = keys[i] ;
    var color1 = all[k].color1;
    var color2 = all[k].color2;
    var color3 = all[k].color3;
    var color4 = all[k].color4;

    var output = '<div id="ProBox"><div id="myBox" class="bigBox animated fadeIn">'+
                      '<div class="top">'+
                        '<div class="box box1" style="background-color: '+ color1 +' "><button id="btnColor1" value="'+ color1 +'"></button></div>'+
                        '<div class="box box2" style="background-color: '+ color2 +' "><button id="btnColor2" value="'+ color2 +'"></button></div>'+
                      '</div>'+
                      '<div class="bootom">'+
                        '<div class="box box3" style="background-color: '+ color3 +' "><button id="btnColor3" value="'+ color3 +'"></button></div>'+
                        '<div class="box box4" style="background-color: '+ color4 +' "><button id="btnColor4" value="'+ color4 +'"></button></div>'+
                      '</div>'+
                    '</div></div>';

    body.innerHTML += output;

    var ProBox = document.getElementById('ProBox');

    Array.prototype.forEach.call(ProBox.children , function(box){
        box.addEventListener('click' , function(){
          console.log(this);
        })
    });

  }
  // end data array


};
```

any help appreciated cheers

Comment: You sure that your forEach iterates on all childrens? Try putting a console.log() or something inside and see what is going on first. Also you can monitor the listeners in Chrome Dev tools and see if they actually exist. I haven't done something like this but it seems to me that you have an issue with creating your listeners.

Answer (score 0):

i fixed buy querySelectorAll to select all of the boxs and then loop into them with for loop and it works just fine